# Xamarin.Android Is too many Handlers counter productive?

Tags: c#, android, tcp, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm doing a cross platform project on Xamarin. 
Came up with this question. I have a TabActivity (Holds 4 Framgents (Request, Info, Fav, Settings). Also I have a TcpController, which is nothing more then a class with a bunch of async tasks. If you look at the following method:

```
public async Task Read( ) {
    await socketListener.StartListeningAsync( port );
    socketListener.ConnectionReceived += async ( sender, args ) => {
        var client = args.SocketClient;
        await Task.Delay( 2000 );
        while (true) {

            System.Console.WriteLine( "Testing.." );
            //Read from the ReadStream property of the socket client to receive data
            if (client.ReadStream.CanRead) {
                await Task.Run( ( ) => client.ReadStream.ReadAsync( dataSet, 0, dataSet.Length ) );
                netObj = networkObjectAdapter.ByteArrayToObject( dataSet );
                if (netObj.command == NetworkCommand.RECEIVE_LIST) {

                    Message msg = new Message( );
                    msg.Obj = dataSet;
                    requestFragmentHandler.SendMessage( msg );

                } else if (netObj.command == NetworkCommand.RECEIVE_VOTE_SONG) {
                    Message msg = new Message( );
                    msg.Obj = dataSet;
                    requestFragmentHandler.SendMessage( msg );
                }
                //other business logic
            }
            await args.SocketClient.DisconnectAsync( );
            break;

        }
    };
}
```

As you can see the in the if statements I use the RequestFragmentHandler to send a message to it when something is received, although I am not sure if having f.e. 3 handlers for each fragment would make sense in regards to the Android architecture. If letting a bunch of handlers handle your communication between fragments and the Tcp Controller is a bad system decision, what would be the best method that does not block the UI?

Comment: Can you add more information to clearify what you are trying to archive?

Comment: Is it ok to have a handler for each fragment, for communication with the TcpController, or is there another way that wouldn't block the UI?